# How to specify Alternate Source Path for Windows Server features

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

I am attempting to install the Network Policy Server role via the Add Roles and Features wizard, which is being run remotely from a management station (i.e. not on the server itself).

It tells me I need to specify an Alternate Source Path for the installation files. I have tried:

```
WIM:\\ad.lifeway.net.au\shared\lifeway-gpo\en_windows_server_2012_r2_x64_dvd_2707946\sources\install.wim
\\ad.lifeway.net.au\shared\lifeway-gpo\en_windows_server_2012_r2_x64_dvd_2707946.iso
\\ad.lifeway.net.au\shared\lifeway-gpo\en_windows_server_2012_r2_x64_dvd_2707946\
\\ad.lifeway.net.au\shared\lifeway-gpo\en_windows_server_2012_r2_x64_dvd_2707946\sources\
\\ad.lifeway.net.au\shared\lifeway-gpo\en_windows_server_2012_r2_x64_dvd_2707946\sources\SxS\
```

**None** of these are working - the wizard just bombs out telling me it can't find the source files required.

What am I missing here?

---

This is a Server Core installation, and I have tried it via PS as well:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[What you're missing, as far as I can tell, is that NPS is not a supported role on Server 2012 Core](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574158.aspx).  (Even though RRAS is.)

---

> When Windows Server 2012 is in Server Core mode, the following server roles are supported:

```
Active Directory Certificate Services

Active Directory Domain Services

DHCP Server

DNS Server

File Services (including File Server Resource Manager)

Active Directory Lightweight Directory Services (AD LDS)

Hyper-V

Print and Document Services

Streaming Media Services

Web Server (including a subset of ASP.NET)

Windows Server Update Server

Active Directory Rights Management Server

Routing and Remote Access Server, including the following sub-roles:

    Remote Desktop Services Connection Broker

    Licensing

    Virtualization
```

Comment: That's a really great error message it gives you when you try to install an unsupported feature. Really informative about what the actual problem is. Way to go Microsoft!

Comment: @MarkHenderson I know, right?  If they're going to make it useless, they could have at least tried to make it amusing, like `ps0: server role on fire!`